# Error deploying Angular2 app on Google Cloud

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, angular-material

I have been attempting to deploy an Angular2 application with Google App Engine and have been running into issues. I get the following error when trying to deploy:

```
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                                                          
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
Application startup error:
yarn start v0.21.3
$ ng serve 
** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:8080 **
 52% building modules 357/395 modules 38 active .../position/overlay-position-builder.js
```

The error seems to point to `@angular/material` given the line `.../position/overlay-position-builder.js`.

I built the app using `@angular-cli`.

There is nothing of value in the logs that I can see.

Any ideas on what the issue might be and how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you share the steps you've taken to reach to the issue?

Comment: To get here I've just been running `gcloud app deploy`. I did already have to move `"@angular/cli": "^1.0.0"` into `dependencies` in addition to `devDependencies` in `package.json` as there was an issue with not having `@angular-cli` installed and the script trying to run `ng serve` and failing. So just to make sure that there was no issue with my app in Google Cloud I downloaded and deployed the `cloud-cardboard-viewer` sample project at codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-cardboard-view‌​er/… and that deployed without issue. Again, I have no issues running locally.

Answer (score 1):

**ISSUE:**
The `ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]` is typically caused by a dependency issue that results in an error of `not found`.

This similar issue, or `sh: 1: ng: not found`, has been reported and worked-around by using creating a Dockerfile [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6486).

In this original post, it appears that `yarn start v0.21.3` is the issue.

---

**SOLUTION:** An Angular2 project created by using the angular-cli will contain the root `package.json` file with a devDependencies section like the example below:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "@angular/cli": "1.4.2",
   ...
   ...
},
```

**NOTE:** To get any other dependencies, like `@angular/material` and commands like `yarn start v0.21.3` to work. The `Dockerfile` must include the commands to install those dependencies via command line.

Create an `app.yaml` and `Dockerfile` within the same path of the package.json file like the example below:

```
angular2-example-app
├── e2e
├── node_modules
├── src
├── package.json
├── app.yaml 
├── Dockerfile
```

The `app.yaml` file will need the following settings: ([app.yaml documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml)):

```
# [start app_yaml]
  runtime: custom
  env: flex
```

The `Dockerfile` will need all the commands a user could call on the command line to assemble an image.

***Note:*** `npm install -g @angular/cli` command being ran in the example below:

```
FROM alpine:latest
MAINTAINER yourname

# update alpine linux
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \ 
    apk add nodejs && \
    # may comment this line in my computer.
    apk add nodejs-npm && \
    npm install -g @angular/cli

# add source code to images
ADD . /angular2-example-app

# switch working directory
WORKDIR /angular2-example-app

# install dependencies
RUN npm install

# expose port 4200
EXPOSE 4200 

# run ng serve on localhost
CMD ["ng","serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--disable-host-check"]
```

Deploy the app to your google cloud App Engine: `gcloud app deploy`

([gcloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy))