# `sh: 1: ng: not found` when I run Google Cloud's `gcloud app deploy`

Tags: angular, npm, google-cloud-platform

I've looked at both [Error deploying Angular2 app on Google Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196069/error-deploying-angular2-app-on-google-cloud) and [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6486), and tried what they suggest, but neither appear to solve my problem. Below is how I have the project configured; if it matters, I try to deploy through the Cloud Shell.

`app.yaml:`

```
runtime: custom
env: flex

manual_scaling: 
  instances: 1
```

`Dockerfile:`

```
FROM alpine:latest
MAINTAINER my-username

# update alpine linux
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \ 
    apk add nodejs && \
    # may comment this line in my computer.
    apk add nodejs-npm && \
    npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.15

# add source code to images
ADD . /my_project_name

# switch working directory
WORKDIR /my_project_name

# install dependencies
RUN npm install

# expose port 4200
EXPOSE 4200 

# run ng serve on localhost
CMD ["ng","serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--disable-host-check"]
```

I even double-check that I have it installed in my `package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.17",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
```

And that, I think, is the only files I need to include. Below are the logs from when I run `deploy`:

```
> my_project@0.0.0 start /app
> ng serve

sh: 1: ng: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
... etc ...
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you not using the `node:latest` base image? You don't want whatever node/npm that comes from the pkg manager

Comment: Also, does the container work locally?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install `Angular CLI` globally

```sh
# update alpine linux
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \ 
    apk add nodejs && \
    # may comment this line in my computer.
    apk add nodejs-npm && \
 # No need   npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.15
```

You should be able to do `npm start` or `yarn start` instead of invoking `ng` binary yourself.

```sh
# run ng serve on localhost
# For NPM
CMD ["npm","start", "--" "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--disable-host-check"]

# For YARN (but you need to install yarn package manager first)
CMD ["yarn","start", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--disable-host-check"]
```

---

On a side note: If you are trying to deploy to a production environment, you should ideally try to build angular app in prod mode (`npm build -- --prod`) and then server static `HTML`, `CSS`, `JS` files using some web server like [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/) or [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/)